# How to get all rows from csv file where 2 columns have the same variable

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file representing soccergames of about 1700 teams (but every team has different series) and  containing 11 columns and 2 columns of them have the same variable (ID number of the team). [example of the page](https://lucshomepage.000webhostapp.com/voetbal.php). The ID's are the same in the 2 columns for the home- and away games.

I explode all rows to an array. But I get only the home games with:

```
if(in_array($stamnr, $col)) {}
```

How can I get home- and away games?

My php code:

```
<?php
   $reeks="";
   if(!empty($_POST['myselection'])) {
     $reeks = $_POST['myselection'];
                            
     echo "<h3><b>REEKS  "   .$reeks . "</b></h3>";

     if (($handle = fopen("test/masterfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                                    $data =   

array_map("utf8_encode", $data); //added
$num = count($data);
                                  
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
$matchen = array();
$col = explode(';',$data[$c]);
if(in_array($stamnr, $col)) {
  $date = str_replace('/', '-', $col[1]);
  $dag = substr($date, 0, 2);
  $maand = substr($date, 3, 2);
  $jaar = substr($date, 6, 4);
  $weekdag = getWeekDay($dag,$maand,$jaar);
  $col[1] = $weekdag."<br />". $col[1];
  $matchen = $col[0]. ', ' .$col[1]. ', ' .$col[2]. ', ' .$col[3]. ', ' .$col[4].', ' .$col[5]. ', ' .$col[6]. ', ' .$col[7];//. ', ' .$col[8]. ', ' .$col[9]. ', ' .$col[10];
$myArray = explode(',', $matchen);
if ($col[0] === $reeks) {
echo "<tr>";
$row++;
foreach($myArray as $key) {
echo "<td>". trim($key)."</td>";
  }
echo "</tr>";
 }
}
}
 

}

    }
      fclose($handle);
     }
        echo "<br /><br />";
    ?>
```

I just have edit the PHP code.

Here a part of the csv file:

```
DIV;DATE;HOUR;HOME;AWAY;RH;RA;STATUS;MD;REGNUMBERHOME;REGNUMBERAWAY
W2B;03/09/2022;18:00;VV Koekelare A;V.V. Tielt ;5;0;;1;02531;00218
W2B;03/09/2022;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K. FC Lissewege A;1;0;;1;04334;04718
W2B;03/09/2022;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K. WS Houthulst A;0;0;;1;08832;02833
W2B;04/09/2022;15:00;SV Loppem ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;1;1;;1;06136;06435
W2B;04/09/2022;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K. SV Bredene ;1;3;;1;04320;04460
W2B;04/09/2022;15:00;Jong Male ;Club Roeselare ;4;0;;1;07951;09360
W2B;04/09/2022;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;K. FC Heist A;2;0;;1;04257;04465
W2B;04/09/2022;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;2;2;;1;05187;06039
W2B;10/09/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;SV Loppem ;2;0;;2;06039;06136
W2B;10/09/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;Jong Male ;2;3;;2;00218;07951
W2B;11/09/2022;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K. Dosko Beveren ;2;2;;2;04460;04334
W2B;11/09/2022;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;K. VC Ardooie ;0;4;;2;04718;04257
W2B;11/09/2022;15:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K.FC Lichtervelde ;4;2;;2;02833;04320
W2B;11/09/2022;15:00;Club Roeselare ;SC Lombardsijde ;3;0;;2;09360;05187
W2B;11/09/2022;15:00;K. FC Heist A;VV Koekelare A;1;1;;2;04465;02531
W2B;11/09/2022;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;Dosko Kanegem ;0;1;;2;06435;08832
W2B;17/09/2022;18:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K. FC Lissewege A;1;2;;3;04320;04718
W2B;17/09/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;0;3;;3;00218;06039
W2B;17/09/2022;19:30;K. Dosko Beveren ;Club Roeselare ;0;2;;3;04334;09360
W2B;18/09/2022;14:00;VV Koekelare A;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;3;1;;3;02531;06435
W2B;18/09/2022;15:00;SV Loppem ;K. WS Houthulst A;1;2;;3;06136;02833
W2B;18/09/2022;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;K. SV Bredene ;1;1;;3;04257;04460
W2B;18/09/2022;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;K. FC Heist A;5;0;;3;05187;04465
W2B;18/09/2022;15:00;Jong Male ;Dosko Kanegem ;1;0;;3;07951;08832
W2B;24/09/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K. Dosko Beveren ;2;4;;4;06039;04334
W2B;24/09/2022;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;V.V. Tielt ;0;0;;4;08832;00218
W2B;25/09/2022;15:00;K. FC Heist A;Jong Male ;0;2;;4;04465;07951
W2B;25/09/2022;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;SC Lombardsijde ;4;4;;4;04718;05187
W2B;25/09/2022;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;VV Koekelare A;0;1;;4;04320;02531
W2B;25/09/2022;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;SV Loppem ;7;0;;4;04460;06136
W2B;25/09/2022;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K. VC Ardooie ;3;3;;4;06435;04257
W2B;01/10/2022;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;0;2;;5;04334;04320
W2B;01/10/2022;19:30;Club Roeselare ;K. FC Lissewege A;1;1;;5;09360;04718
W2B;02/10/2022;14:00;VV Koekelare A;Dosko Kanegem ;2;0;;5;02531;08832
W2B;02/10/2022;15:00;Jong Male ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;4;3;;5;07951;06039
W2B;02/10/2022;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;0;1;;5;05187;06435
W2B;02/10/2022;15:00;K. FC Heist A;K. SV Bredene ;2;1;;5;04465;04460
W2B;02/10/2022;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;K. WS Houthulst A;4;2;;5;04257;02833
W2B;02/10/2022;15:00;V.V. Tielt ;SV Loppem ;3;2;;5;00218;06136
W2B;08/10/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K. VC Ardooie ;1;0;;6;06039;04257
W2B;08/10/2022;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K. FC Heist A;1;1;;6;02833;04465
W2B;08/10/2022;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K. FC Lissewege A;1;8;;6;08832;04718
W2B;09/10/2022;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;VV Koekelare A;2;2;;6;04460;02531
W2B;09/10/2022;15:00;SV Loppem ;K. Dosko Beveren ;0;0;;6;06136;04334
W2B;09/10/2022;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;Jong Male ;2;0;;6;05187;07951
W2B;09/10/2022;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;Club Roeselare ;0;0;;6;06435;09360
W2B;09/10/2022;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;V.V. Tielt ;1;1;;6;04320;00218
W2B;15/10/2022;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K. WS Houthulst A;1;1;;7;02531;02833
W2B;15/10/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;1;1;;7;00218;06435
W2B;15/10/2022;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;SC Lombardsijde ;2;3;;7;04334;05187
W2B;16/10/2022;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;Dosko Kanegem ;2;1;;7;04257;08832
W2B;16/10/2022;15:00;Jong Male ;SV Loppem ;4;3;;7;07951;06136
W2B;16/10/2022;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;K. SV Bredene ;0;3;;7;04718;04460
W2B;16/10/2022;15:00;K. FC Heist A;K.FC Lichtervelde ;0;1;;7;04465;04320
W2B;16/10/2022;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;0;4;;7;09360;06039
W2B;22/10/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;VV Koekelare A;4;2;;8;06039;02531
W2B;22/10/2022;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K. Dosko Beveren ;0;1;;8;08832;04334
W2B;22/10/2022;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;V.V. Tielt ;4;1;;8;02833;00218
W2B;23/10/2022;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K. VC Ardooie ;0;3;;8;04320;04257
W2B;23/10/2022;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;Jong Male ;1;3;;8;06435;07951
W2B;23/10/2022;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;K. FC Heist A;4;1;;8;04718;04465
W2B;23/10/2022;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;SC Lombardsijde ;6;2;;8;04460;05187
W2B;23/10/2022;15:00;SV Loppem ;Club Roeselare ;2;4;;8;06136;09360
W2B;26/10/2022;20:00;K. WS Houthulst A;Club Roeselare ;1;2;;4;02833;09360
W2B;29/10/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K. SV Bredene ;1;2;;9;06039;04460
W2B;29/10/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K. FC Lissewege A;2;1;;9;00218;04718
W2B;29/10/2022;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K. FC Heist A;2;1;;9;04334;04465
W2B;30/10/2022;14:30;SV Loppem ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;2;1;;9;06136;04320
W2B;30/10/2022;14:30;SC Lombardsijde ;K. VC Ardooie ;0;2;;9;05187;04257
W2B;30/10/2022;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K. WS Houthulst A;1;6;;9;06435;02833
W2B;30/10/2022;15:00;Club Roeselare ;Dosko Kanegem ;1;0;;9;09360;08832
W2B;30/10/2022;15:00;Jong Male ;VV Koekelare A;1;2;;9;07951;02531
W2B;05/11/2022;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;2;1;;10;08832;06039
W2B;06/11/2022;14:30;K.FC Lichtervelde ;SC Lombardsijde ;2;1;;10;04320;05187
W2B;06/11/2022;14:30;K. VC Ardooie ;Jong Male ;3;2;;10;04257;07951
W2B;06/11/2022;15:00;K. FC Heist A;Club Roeselare ;1;0;;10;04465;09360
W2B;06/11/2022;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;V.V. Tielt ;5;0;;10;04460;00218
W2B;06/11/2022;15:00;VV Koekelare A;SV Loppem ;2;2;;10;02531;06136
W2B;06/11/2022;15:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;0;3;;10;04334;06435
W2B;12/11/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;2;1;;11;06039;04320
W2B;12/11/2022;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K. SV Bredene ;1;1;;11;02833;04460
W2B;12/11/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K. VC Ardooie ;0;1;;11;00218;04257
W2B;13/11/2022;14:30;SV Loppem ;K. FC Lissewege A;0;1;;11;06136;04718
W2B;13/11/2022;14:30;SC Lombardsijde ;Dosko Kanegem ;0;0;;11;05187;08832
W2B;13/11/2022;15:00;Jong Male ;K. Dosko Beveren ;3;0;;11;07951;04334
W2B;13/11/2022;15:00;Club Roeselare ;VV Koekelare A;3;1;;11;09360;02531
W2B;13/11/2022;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K. FC Heist A;0;1;;11;06435;04465
W2B;19/11/2022;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K. Dosko Beveren ;3;1;;12;02531;04334
W2B;19/11/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;SC Lombardsijde ;2;1;;12;00218;05187
W2B;19/11/2022;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;Jong Male ;4;1;;12;02833;07951
W2B;20/11/2022;14:30;K. VC Ardooie ;SV Loppem ;2;1;;12;04257;06136
W2B;20/11/2022;14:30;K.FC Lichtervelde ;Club Roeselare ;1;1;;12;04320;09360
W2B;20/11/2022;15:00;K. FC Heist A;Dosko Kanegem ;3;0;;12;04465;08832
W2B;20/11/2022;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;K. SKV Zwevezele ;0;2;;12;04718;06039
W2B;20/11/2022;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;4;0;;12;04460;06435
W2B;26/11/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K. WS Houthulst A;2;3;;13;06039;02833
W2B;26/11/2022;19:00;Jong Male ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;6;2;;13;07951;04320
W2B;26/11/2022;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K. SV Bredene ;0;5;;13;08832;04460
W2B;26/11/2022;19:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K. FC Lissewege A;1;0;;13;06435;04718
W2B;26/11/2022;20:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K. VC Ardooie ;0;1;;13;04334;04257
W2B;26/11/2022;20:45;Club Roeselare ;V.V. Tielt ;0;1;;13;09360;00218
W2B;30/11/2022;20:00;K. FC Lissewege A;K. WS Houthulst A;1;1;;10;04718;02833
W2B;03/12/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K. FC Heist A;3;0;;14;06039;04465
W2B;03/12/2022;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;SC Lombardsijde ;6;1;;14;02833;05187
W2B;03/12/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K. Dosko Beveren ;5;1;;14;00218;04334
W2B;04/12/2022;14:30;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;1;0;;14;04320;06435
W2B;04/12/2022;14:30;SV Loppem ;Dosko Kanegem ;1;2;;14;06136;08832
W2B;04/12/2022;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;Jong Male ;8;1;;14;04460;07951
W2B;04/12/2022;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;Club Roeselare ;1;0;;14;04257;09360
W2B;04/12/2022;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;VV Koekelare A;1;4;;14;04718;02531
W2B;10/12/2022;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K. VC Ardooie ;0;0;;15;02531;04257
W2B;10/12/2022;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K. WS Houthulst A;2;2;;15;04334;02833
W2B;10/12/2022;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;1;0;;15;08832;04320
W2B;11/12/2022;14:30;SC Lombardsijde ;SV Loppem ;1;5;;15;05187;06136
W2B;11/12/2022;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K. SV Bredene ;1;2;;15;09360;04460
W2B;11/12/2022;15:00;Jong Male ;K. FC Lissewege A;5;2;;15;07951;04718
W2B;11/12/2022;15:00;K. FC Heist A;V.V. Tielt ;1;1;;15;04465;00218
W2B;11/12/2022;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;3;2;;15;06435;06039
W2B;17/12/2022;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;Club Roeselare ;1;1;;16;06039;09360
W2B;17/12/2022;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;Dosko Kanegem ;0;2;;16;00218;08832
W2B;17/12/2022;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;VV Koekelare A;5;2;;16;02833;02531
W2B;17/12/2022;19:30;K. FC Lissewege A;K. Dosko Beveren ;1;1;;16;04718;04334
W2B;18/12/2022;13:30;Jong Male ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;3;1;;16;07951;06435
W2B;18/12/2022;13:30;SV Loppem ;K. SV Bredene ;0;3;;16;06136;04460
W2B;08/01/2023;14:30;SC Lombardsijde ;VV Koekelare A;0;4;;13;05187;02531
W2B;08/01/2023;14:30;SV Loppem ;K. FC Heist A;1;8;;13;06136;04465
W2B;11/01/2023;20:00;K. VC Ardooie ;SC Lombardsijde ;2;2;;16;04257;05187
W2B;14/01/2023;18:00;VV Koekelare A;Jong Male ;1;2;;17;02531;07951
W2B;14/01/2023;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K. VC Ardooie ;1;1;;17;08832;04257
W2B;14/01/2023;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;1;0;;17;04334;06039
W2B;15/01/2023;14:30;SC Lombardsijde ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;0;0;;17;05187;04320
W2B;15/01/2023;15:00;K. FC Heist A;K. WS Houthulst A;2;1;;17;04465;02833
W2B;15/01/2023;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;V.V. Tielt ;2;1;;17;06435;00218
W2B;15/01/2023;15:00;Club Roeselare ;SV Loppem ;4;1;;17;09360;06136
W2B;15/01/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K. FC Lissewege A;9;0;;17;04460;04718
W2B;21/01/2023;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;SC Lombardsijde ;3;1;;18;06039;05187
W2B;21/01/2023;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;Dosko Kanegem ;2;0;;18;02833;08832
W2B;21/01/2023;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K. SV Bredene ;0;2;;18;00218;04460
W2B;22/01/2023;14:30;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K. Dosko Beveren ;2;2;;18;04320;04334
W2B;22/01/2023;14:30;SV Loppem ;VV Koekelare A;0;8;;18;06136;02531
W2B;22/01/2023;14:30;K. VC Ardooie ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;1;0;;18;04257;06435
W2B;22/01/2023;15:00;Jong Male ;K. FC Heist A;4;2;;18;07951;04465
W2B;22/01/2023;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;Club Roeselare ;2;2;;18;04718;09360
W2B;28/01/2023;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K.FC Lichtervelde ;3;3;;19;02531;04320
W2B;28/01/2023;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;SC Lombardsijde ;3;1;;19;08832;05187
W2B;28/01/2023;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;Jong Male ;1;3;;19;04334;07951
W2B;28/01/2023;19:00;K. FC Heist A;K. VC Ardooie ;1;3;;19;04465;04257
W2B;29/01/2023;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;SV Loppem ;1;1;;19;06435;06136
W2B;29/01/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;1;0;;19;04460;06039
W2B;29/01/2023;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;V.V. Tielt ;2;2;;19;04718;00218
W2B;29/01/2023;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K. WS Houthulst A;3;2;;19;09360;02833
W2B;04/02/2023;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K. FC Lissewege A;7;0;;20;06039;04718
W2B;04/02/2023;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;2;2;;20;02833;06435
W2B;04/02/2023;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;VV Koekelare A;0;1;;20;08832;02531
W2B;05/02/2023;15:00;SV Loppem ;V.V. Tielt ;1;4;;20;06136;00218
W2B;05/02/2023;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;Jong Male ;1;2;;20;04320;07951
W2B;05/02/2023;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;K. Dosko Beveren ;2;2;;20;04257;04334
W2B;05/02/2023;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;Club Roeselare ;2;4;;20;05187;09360
W2B;05/02/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K. FC Heist A;4;0;;20;04460;04465
W2B;11/02/2023;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K. SKV Zwevezele ;0;0;;21;02531;06039
W2B;11/02/2023;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;Dosko Kanegem ;2;0;;21;04334;08832
W2B;11/02/2023;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K. WS Houthulst A;1;2;;21;00218;02833
W2B;12/02/2023;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;1;0;;21;04257;04320
W2B;12/02/2023;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;2;1;;21;09360;06435
W2B;12/02/2023;15:00;Jong Male ;K. SV Bredene ;2;3;;21;07951;04460
W2B;12/02/2023;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;SV Loppem ;4;1;;21;04718;06136
W2B;12/02/2023;15:00;K. FC Heist A;SC Lombardsijde ;4;1;;21;04465;05187
W2B;19/02/2023;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K. FC Heist A;1;4;;16;04320;04465
W2B;25/02/2023;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;V.V. Tielt ;2;0;;22;06039;00218
W2B;25/02/2023;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K. FC Heist A;1;2;;22;08832;04465
W2B;25/02/2023;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K. FC Lissewege A;5;1;;22;02833;04718
W2B;26/02/2023;15:00;SV Loppem ;Jong Male ;1;4;;22;06136;07951
W2B;26/02/2023;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;3;2;;22;09360;04320
W2B;26/02/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K. VC Ardooie ;3;0;;22;04460;04257
W2B;26/02/2023;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;VV Koekelare A;1;1;;22;06435;02531
W2B;26/02/2023;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;K. Dosko Beveren ;0;2;;22;05187;04334
W2B;04/03/2023;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K. SV Bredene ;;;;23;02531;04460
W2B;04/03/2023;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;SV Loppem ;;;;23;02833;06136
W2B;04/03/2023;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;Club Roeselare ;;;;23;00218;09360
W2B;05/03/2023;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;;;;23;04718;06435
W2B;05/03/2023;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;;;;23;04257;06039
W2B;05/03/2023;15:00;K. FC Heist A;K. Dosko Beveren ;;;;23;04465;04334
W2B;05/03/2023;15:00;Jong Male ;SC Lombardsijde ;;;;23;07951;05187
W2B;05/03/2023;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;Dosko Kanegem ;;;;23;04320;08832
W2B;11/03/2023;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;Jong Male ;;;;24;06039;07951
W2B;11/03/2023;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;VV Koekelare A;;;;24;04334;02531
W2B;12/03/2023;15:00;K. FC Heist A;K. FC Lissewege A;;;;24;04465;04718
W2B;12/03/2023;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;V.V. Tielt ;;;;24;05187;00218
W2B;12/03/2023;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;;;;24;06435;04320
W2B;12/03/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K. WS Houthulst A;;;;24;04460;02833
W2B;12/03/2023;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K. VC Ardooie ;;;;24;09360;04257
W2B;12/03/2023;15:00;Dosko Kanegem ;SV Loppem ;;;;24;08832;06136
W2B;18/03/2023;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K. FC Heist A;;;;25;02531;04465
W2B;18/03/2023;18:00;K. FC Lissewege A;Dosko Kanegem ;;;;25;04718;08832
W2B;18/03/2023;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K. SKV Zwevezele ;;;;25;02833;06039
W2B;19/03/2023;15:00;V.V. Tielt ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;;;;25;00218;04320
W2B;19/03/2023;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K. Dosko Beveren ;;;;25;09360;04334
W2B;19/03/2023;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K. SV Bredene ;;;;25;06435;04460
W2B;19/03/2023;15:00;Jong Male ;K. VC Ardooie ;;;;25;07951;04257
W2B;19/03/2023;15:00;SV Loppem ;SC Lombardsijde ;;;;25;06136;05187
W2B;25/03/2023;18:30;K. SKV Zwevezele ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;;;;26;06039;06435
W2B;25/03/2023;19:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;V.V. Tielt ;;;;26;04334;00218
W2B;25/03/2023;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;Jong Male ;;;;26;08832;07951
W2B;26/03/2023;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K. WS Houthulst A;;;;26;04320;02833
W2B;26/03/2023;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;VV Koekelare A;;;;26;04257;02531
W2B;26/03/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;Club Roeselare ;;;;26;04460;09360
W2B;26/03/2023;15:00;K. FC Heist A;SV Loppem ;;;;26;04465;06136
W2B;26/03/2023;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;K. FC Lissewege A;;;;26;05187;04718
W2B;01/04/2023;18:00;SV Loppem ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;;;;27;06136;06039
W2B;01/04/2023;18:00;K. FC Lissewege A;K.FC Lichtervelde ;;;;27;04718;04320
W2B;01/04/2023;18:00;VV Koekelare A;SC Lombardsijde ;;;;27;02531;05187
W2B;01/04/2023;19:00;V.V. Tielt ;K. FC Heist A;;;;27;00218;04465
W2B;01/04/2023;19:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K. VC Ardooie ;;;;27;02833;04257
W2B;01/04/2023;19:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;K. Dosko Beveren ;;;;27;06435;04334
W2B;01/04/2023;19:30;Club Roeselare ;Jong Male ;;;;27;09360;07951
W2B;02/04/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;Dosko Kanegem ;;;;27;04460;08832
W2B;15/04/2023;18:00;VV Koekelare A;K. FC Lissewege A;;;;28;02531;04718
W2B;15/04/2023;19:00;Dosko Kanegem ;Club Roeselare ;;;;28;08832;09360
W2B;16/04/2023;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;K. SKV Zwevezele ;;;;28;04320;06039
W2B;16/04/2023;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;K. SV Bredene ;;;;28;05187;04460
W2B;16/04/2023;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;V.V. Tielt ;;;;28;04257;00218
W2B;16/04/2023;15:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;SV Loppem ;;;;28;04334;06136
W2B;16/04/2023;15:00;Jong Male ;K. WS Houthulst A;;;;28;07951;02833
W2B;16/04/2023;15:00;K. FC Heist A;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;;;;28;04465;06435
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;K. SKV Zwevezele ;Dosko Kanegem ;;;;29;06039;08832
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;SC Lombardsijde ;;;;29;06435;05187
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;K. SV Bredene ;K.FC Lichtervelde ;;;;29;04460;04320
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;Club Roeselare ;K. FC Heist A;;;;29;09360;04465
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;K. FC Lissewege A;Jong Male ;;;;29;04718;07951
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;V.V. Tielt ;VV Koekelare A;;;;29;00218;02531
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;K. WS Houthulst A;K. Dosko Beveren ;;;;29;02833;04334
W2B;23/04/2023;15:00;SV Loppem ;K. VC Ardooie ;;;;29;06136;04257
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;VV Koekelare A;Club Roeselare ;;;;30;02531;09360
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;K.FC Lichtervelde ;SV Loppem ;;;;30;04320;06136
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;Jong Male ;V.V. Tielt ;;;;30;07951;00218
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;SC Lombardsijde ;K. WS Houthulst A;;;;30;05187;02833
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;K. FC Heist A;K. SKV Zwevezele ;;;;30;04465;06039
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;K. VC Ardooie ;K. FC Lissewege A;;;;30;04257;04718
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;K. Dosko Beveren ;K. SV Bredene ;;;;30;04334;04460
W2B;30/04/2023;15:00;Dosko Kanegem ;K.S.K. Snaaskerke ;;;;30;08832;06435
```

To test only team with ID 04334 and serie W2B can be used with this part of CSV.

Comment: Please provide example of what your CSV has. You should use the native CSV parsing functions, not explode. Please add your code so we know what you are doing also.

Comment: It is a file of about 22 MB, can I put it here?

Comment: Perhaps just post an representative part, that has the "2 columns with the same variable"

Comment: If you specified the _correct_ separator in your fgetcsv call, then you would not need `$col = explode(';',$data[$c]);` later on. Right now, you are not handling the reading part correctly at all here.

Comment: Your "CSV" isn't a comma separated file. As noted previously your delimiter is a semi-colon. `fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")`.

Comment: Likely unrelated currently but your `utf8_encode ` usage is likely also incorrect. > 90% of the time that function is used it is incorrect. The manual has the following warning on it for that exact reason,`Relying on this function is highly discouraged `.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate split by HOME/AWAY columns in two separate array for hardcoded footbalcommand

```
$rw = array_map('str_getcsv', file($pathToCsv));
$len = count($rw);
$club = 'VV Koekelare A';
$gameHome = [];
$gameAway = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $elt = $rw[$i];

    //home and away columns
    if ($elt[3] === $club) {
        $gameHome[] = $elt;
    }

    if ($elt[4] === $club) {
        $gameAway[] = $elt;
    }
}

var_dump($gameHome, $gameAway);
```

Now you can merge and do other manipulations with two arrays by date and other columns into one.

Comment: when I place this in the first line:
$rw = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test/masterfile.csv'));
I get this error: 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /storage/ssd5/212/20059212/public_html/testreeks.php on line 6

Comment: This is putting the whole CSV file into memory, then parsing those values into a new arrays so this would require 2-3* the amount of memory your file is, also would require php configuration to allow for that amount of memory consumption.